# How to create oozie.war?

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, oozie

I am using `oozie-3.3.0.` In this i am unable to find `oozie.war` in `${OOZIE_HOME}` directory. When i execute this command

```
./addtowar.sh -inputwar ${OOZIE_HOME}/oozie.war -outputwar oozie-new.war -hadoop 0.20.205.0 ${HADOOP_HOME} -extjs /home/oozie/ext-2.2.zip
```

> I get oozie.war not found.

How can I create oozie.war?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the 3.3.0 release of OOZIE doesn't come with the war pre-built. You should be able to follow the instructions on Building an Oozie distribution:

- http://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/ENG_Building.html#Building_an_Oozie_Distribution

Comment: Thanks Chris can you please send me any link for good clear simple documentation.

Comment: When i try to run this command "oozie job -oozie http://localhost:8080/oozie -config job.properties -submit"
I got this Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.oozie.cli.OozieCLI
can anyone help me where i went wrong